# Closing table tags displaying in html email

Tags: html-email, outlook-2003

Edit to add my code.

I have designed and coded a new html email template for my business, I am 99.99% sure that all my table tags have been closed properly but when I get the email in Outlook 2003 there are (two) random closing  and  tags. I've ran the online version of the email through the W3Cs validator and it all validates fine.

Anyone ever come across this before? Or is this something I will just have to live with along with the several other issues there are with html emails?

Result of the email can be found [here](http://s9.postimage.org/v37g3s4un/email.jpg).

My code:

```
<!-- Main holding table -->
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#350d03">
    <tr><!-- Main holding table row -->
        <td><!-- Main holding table data -->
            <!-- Header table -->
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">
                <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                    <td height="30" width="600"></td>
                </tr><!-- End spacer row -->
                <tr>
                    <td width="600" align="center"><a href="http://www.example.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="linktoimage" alt="Western House Hotel" title="Western House Hotel" border="0" width="312" height="38" /></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                    <td height="20" width="600"></td>
                </tr><!-- End spacer row -->
            </table> <!-- End header table -->   
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- Main image feature table -->
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td width="600"><img src="linktoimage" alt="Western House Hotel" title="Western House Hotel" width="600" height="340" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table><!-- End main image feature table -->        
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- Book direct with us table -->
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" bgcolor="#210401" align="center">
                <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                    <td height="10" width="25"></td>
                    <td height="10" width="400"></td>
                    <td height="10" width="150"></td>
                    <td height="10" width="25"></td>
                </tr><!-- End space row -->
                <tr>
                    <td height="10" width="25"></td>
                    <td width="400" valign="middle"><p style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; color: #ffffff; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; text-transform: uppercase;">For best available rates <span style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #bb8d09; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; text-transform: none;">book direct with us</span></p></td>
                    <td height="10" width="150" align="right"><a href="http://www.example.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="linktoimage" alt="Visit our website" title="Visit our website" border="0" width="136" height="28" /></a></td>
                    <td height="10" width="25"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                    <td height="10" width="25"></td>
                    <td height="10" width="400"></td>
                    <td height="10" width="150"></td>
                    <td height="10" width="25"></td>
                </tr><!-- End space row -->    
            </table><!-- End book direct with us table --> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- Main content table -->
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">
                <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="265"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="20"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="265"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                </tr><!-- End spacer row -->
                <tr>
                    <td height="25" width="25"></td>
                    <td height="25" width="550" colspan="3" align="center"><img src="linktoimage" alt="Page divide" width="548" height="18" /></td>
                    <td height="25" width="25"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="265"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="20"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="265"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                </tr><!-- End spacer row -->
                <tr>
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="265">
                        <!-- Main feature left table -->
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="265" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="265"><p style="font-size: 20px; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; color: #350d03; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; text-transform: uppercase;">Special Valentines Package!</p></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                                <td height="15" width="265"></td>
                            </tr><!-- End spacer row -->
                            <tr>
                                <td width="265"><p style="font-size: 16px; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #bb8d09; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">Stay and dine in the beautiful 4 star Western House Hotel between 9th and 17th February for only &pound;139*!</p></td>
                            </tr>  
                            <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                                <td height="25" width="265"></td>
                            </tr><!-- End spacer row -->
                            <tr>
                                <td width="265" align="left" valign="middle"><a href="http://www.example.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="linktoimage" alt="Book Now!" title="Book Now!" border="0" width="114" height="27" /></a></td>
                            </tr>      
                        </table><!-- End main feature left table -->        
                    </td>
                    <td height="20" width="20"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="265"><img src="linktoimage" alt="Special Valentines Package" title="Special Valentines Package" width="265" height="175" /></td>
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="265"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="20"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="265"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                </tr><!-- End spacer row -->
                <tr>
                    <td height="25" width="25"></td>
                    <td height="25" width="550" colspan="3" align="center"><img src="linktoimage" alt="Page divide" width="548" height="18" /></td>
                    <td height="25" width="25"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="265"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="20"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="265"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                </tr><!-- End spacer row -->
                <tr>
                    <td width="25"></td>
                    <td width="265">
                        <!-- Sub feature table left -->
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="265" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="265"><img src="linktoimage" alt="Mother's Day Treat" title="Mother's Day Treat" width="265" height="140" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="15" width="265"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="265"><p style="font-size: 17px; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; color: #350d03; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; text-transform: uppercase;">Mother's Day Treat!</p></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="10" width="265"></td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr>
                                <td width="265"><p style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #7a7a7a; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">Treat your mother to a fantastic dinner and a nights stay in the 4 star Western House Hotel for only &pound;139*!</p></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="25" width="265"></td>
                            </tr>   
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="http://www.example.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="linktoimage" alt="Book Now!" title="Book Now!" border="0" width="114" height="27" /></a></td>
                            </tr>    
                        </table><!-- End sub feature table left -->        
                    </td>
                    <td width="20"></td>
                    <td width="265">
                    <!-- Sub feature table right -->
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="265" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="265"><img src="linktoimage" alt="Mother's Day Treat" title="Mother's Day Treat" width="265" height="140" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="15" width="265"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="265"><p style="font-size: 17px; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; color: #350d03; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; text-transform: uppercase;">Easter Special Offer!</p></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="10" width="265"></td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr>
                                <td width="265"><p style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #7a7a7a; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">Stay in the 4 star Western House Hotel for 2 nights for only &pound;135 per night and 3 nights for only &pound;125 per night**!</p></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td height="25" width="265"></td>
                            </tr>   
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="http://www.example.co.uk" target="_blank"><img src="linktoimage" alt="Book Now!" title="Book Now!" border="0" width="114" height="27" /></a></td>
                            </tr>    
                        </table><!-- End sub feature table right -->
                    </td>
                    <td width="25"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="265"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="20"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="265"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                </tr><!-- End spacer row -->
                <tr>
                    <td height="25" width="25"></td>
                    <td height="25" width="550" colspan="3" align="center"><img src="linktoimage" alt="Page divide" width="548" height="18" /></td>
                    <td height="25" width="25"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="265"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="20"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="265"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                </tr><!-- End spacer row -->
                <tr>
                    <td height="25" width="25"></td>
                    <td height="25" width="550" colspan="3" align="left"><p style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; color: #350d03; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">Terms and conditions</p></td>
                    <td height="25" width="25"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td height="25" width="25"></td>
                    <td height="25" width="550" colspan="3" align="left"><p style="font-size: 11px; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #7a7a7a; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">* Based on two guests sharing. ** Per room per night on a dinner, bed and breakfast basis, based on two guests sharing. Subject to availability. Upgrades available.</p></td>
                    <td height="25" width="25"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="265"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="20"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="265"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                </tr><!-- End spacer row -->                   
            </table><!-- End main content table -->                                     
        </td><!-- End main holding table data -->
    </tr><!-- End main holding table row -->                                  
</table> <!-- End main holding table --> 

<!-- Footer spacer table -->
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#350d03">
    <tr><!-- Footer spacer table row -->
        <td><!-- Footer spacer table data -->
            <!-- Spacer table -->
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" bgcolor="#350d03" align="center">
                <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                    <td height="30" width="600"></td>
                </tr><!-- End spacer row -->
            </table><!-- End spacer table -->
        </td><!-- End footer spacer table data -->
    </tr><!-- End footer spacer table row -->
</table><!-- End footer spacer table -->

<!-- Footer holding table -->
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#210401">
    <tr><!-- Footer holding table row -->
        <td><!-- Footer holding table data -->
            <!-- Footer table -->
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="600" bgcolor="#210401" align="center">
                <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="265"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="20"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="265"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                </tr><!-- End spacer row -->
                <tr>
                    <td height="30" width="25"></td>
                    <td height="30" width="265">
                        <!-- Connect table -->
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="265" bgcolor="#210401" align="center">    
                            <tr>
                                <td width="265" colspan="3"><p style="font-size: 20px; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #bb8d09; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">Connect with Us</p></td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                                <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                                <td height="20" width="15"></td>
                                <td height="20" width="225"></td>
                            </tr><!-- End spacer row -->
                            <tr>
                                <td width="25"><img src="linktoimage" alt="Find us on Facebook" title="Find us on Facebook" width="25" height="25" /></td>
                                <td width="15"></td>
                                <td width="225"><p style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"><a href="http://www.example.co.uk" target="_blank" title="Find us on Facebook" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;">facebook.com/westernhousehotel</a></p></td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                                <td height="10" width="25"></td>
                                <td height="10" width="15"></td>
                                <td height="10" width="225"></td>
                            </tr><!-- End spacer row -->
                            <tr>
                                <td width="25"><img src="http://www.example.co.uk" alt="Follow us on Twitter" title="Follow us on Twitter" width="25" height="25" /></td>
                                <td width="15"></td>
                                <td width="225"><p style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"><a href="http://www.example.co.uk" target="_blank" title="Follow us on Twitter" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;">twitter.com/westernhouseayr</a></p></td>
                            </tr> 
                        </table><!-- End connect table -->  
                    </td>
                    <td height="30" width="20"></td>
                    <td height="30" width="265">
                    <!-- Connect table -->
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="265" bgcolor="#210401" align="center">    
                            <tr>
                                <td width="265" colspan="3"><p style="font-size: 20px; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #bb8d09; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">Contact Us</p></td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                                <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                                <td height="20" width="15"></td>
                                <td height="20" width="225"></td>
                            </tr><!-- End spacer row -->
                            <tr>
                                <td height="25" width="225" colspan="3"><p style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">01292 294990</p></td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                                <td height="10" width="25"></td>
                                <td height="10" width="15"></td>
                                <td height="10" width="225"></td>
                            </tr><!-- End spacer row -->
                            <tr>
                                <td height="25" width="225" colspan="3"><p style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"><a href="http://www.example.co.uk" target="_blank" title="Send us an Email" style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;">info@westernhousehotel.co.uk</a></p></td>
                            </tr> 
                        </table><!-- End connect table -->
                    </td>
                    <td height="30" width="25"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                    <td height="30" width="25"></td>
                    <td height="30" width="265"></td>
                    <td height="30" width="20"></td>
                    <td height="30" width="265"></td>
                    <td height="30" width="25"></td>
                </tr><!-- End spacer row -->
                <tr>
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="500" colspan="3" align="center"><p style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; color: #ffffff; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;">Western House Hotel | Craigie Road | Ayr, South Ayrshire | Scotland | KA7 0HA</p></td>
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><!-- Spacer row -->
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="265"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="20"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="265"></td>
                    <td height="20" width="25"></td>
                </tr><!-- End spacer row -->
            </table><!-- End footer table -->
        </td><!-- End footer holding table data -->
    </tr><!-- End footer holding table row -->
</table><!-- End footer holding table -->                       


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide your code.

Comment: Need the code. Never had it happen, so it is in there somewhere

Comment: Ok thanks. Will post my code tomorrow when I get back to work. I will warn you though, it's pretty long!

Comment: Weird. I checked the code for errors using the W3C HTML Validator and it passed with no errors.

Comment: Yeah I checked the code too for the online version of the email and got no errors either, that's why I am stumped. Thanks for checking.

Comment: In your provided code, there is no DOCTYPE, nor opening html, nor opening body tags. These being missing could cause some oddities in rendering.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to look at the code of your page in Outlook. It will be messy, but it will at least tell you why the `</td>`'s are floating there. There is probably a messed up span or something there.

From there you'll just have to troubleshoot, try some of the following:

- set your charset `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`
- try `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">` doctag

If this doesn't work, try:

- removing the `<p>` tag and using `<br>`'s where the issue occurs to see if Outlook handles that are differently
- try shortening your email leaving the error section the same to see if it is related to the length of your code

Not saying that those things are always necessary, but you'll need to isolate what Outlook 'doesn't like', even if the solution seems silly by normal web standards.

Comment: following along this train of thought, Outlook is problematic when it comes to "empty" table cells. If there is a width and height declared, but no content, it may treat the cell as a "nothing" item. In web pages this might not be an issue, however using Word as a rendering engine (thanks Microsoft!) Nothing cells merge into their parents, and that is probably where these issues are emerging.-- if you can't pinpoint the issue using the method above, start adding non-breaking spaces &nbsp into each empty td.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just sending the inner html of the body? I would of just added this as a comment but apparently I can't until I get a higher reputation. I tried sending the inner html and I didn't have any extraneous tags through Powershell. HOw exactly are you sending it?

Comment: I send the email version without the doctype etc but the online version e.g. 'View in browser' option is a normal HTML document. We send it through a crm we have had specifically made (built in Sugar). I've never had any issue before so was stumped to why I was seeing closing tags that weren't supposed to be there. Thanks.

Comment: That must not be all the html otherwise you're missing the opening html and body tags. Have you tried sending the body inner html?

Comment: Yes I have tried that. I wasn't aware that the emailable version needed the html and body tags? I have two versions, 1) What you see above gets sent through our crm. 2) An online version that is a full web page (with html and body tags), this is used for the "View this email in your browser" link. Thanks.

Comment: `</body> </html> ` needs to be removed from the html that gets sent to the crm. I don't supply the html and body tags when sending out html emails, just the inner html (everything between `<body> </body>`).